# How to validate input when submit without refreshing the page in Laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

if I have a unique column it will send a validate notif that indicates that this email already exists When I submit my input. I want to implement it in Laravel. Please, help me to start with this. Thanks

Comment: When your question contains "without refreshing the page" the answer is always `ajax / xhr`.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for the example but you can you use jQuery Ajax as well

```html
 axios.post('/login', loginParams).then(function (r) {
                   //Do in case of success
                }).catch(function () {
                    new Noty({
                        type: 'Danger',
                        text: '<b>' + r.data.success.name + '</b>',
                    }).show();
 });
```

And in laravel

```html
    public function validator(Request $request)
    {   
         $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        ]);

    }
```